# Android - Set property according to orientation

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

How can I set, for example, a ListView `"app:layout_constraintWidth_percent"` property according to the screen orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support different layouts for different screen sizes and orientations, you create different folders and XML files for each layout. See https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#alternative-layouts and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources for details about how to do this.

You can provide different values for any resource using these techniques, not just layouts.

Comment: Thank you my friend. After reading the links that you provided I managed to create a landscape layout behavior by using the "Create Landscape Variation" option in the orientation menu in "Preview" of the layout.